# PHP: showing content of a folder with icons

Tags: php, pdf, directory

I'm using PHP/MySQL. 
I have a folder called "docs" with PDF files. 
I'd like to know if there exist an easy way, using only PHP, to show the content of the folder with a custom icon. 
I mean, something like this:

```
[icon] File01.pdf
[icon] File02.pdf
[icon] File03.pdf
```

In order to allow visitors read or download the files.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "only" PHP?  You still need a web server to host the PHP and most web servers could show the list of files from a folder without needing PHP.  Also, where does the icon come from?  Is it the same for each or different somehow?  If different, how is the image chosen?

Comment: I rejected your edit because an answer should be marked (e.g. if @Karl answered it) or you should post your answer like everyone else and not edit your answer into the question. - ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the final solution:

```
<?php

    foreach(glob('docs/*.pdf') as $file) {
        echo '<a href=' . $file . '><img src="img/file_pdf.png">' . substr($file, 5, -4) . '</a></br>';
    }

?>
```

I have used **@Karl's** and **Martin's** answers to get the result I was looking for, but all answers were really useful.

**Many thanks to all**

Answer (score 2):

With `glob()` you can get the path to all pdf files and then loop through them with a foreach loop.

```
foreach(glob('*.pdf') as $file) {
    echo '<img src="myicon.png"> ' . $file;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pathinfo to get the file extention and show and png with the extention

```
$fileExt = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo '<a href="path-to-file"><img src="path-to-icons/"' . strtolower($fileExt) . '.png" />' . $filename . '</a>'
```